# How to align button and icon in same row

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

Code below produces button and icon:

[image: wrong alignment]

Button and input box are not in same row. Icon is outside button.

How to force dropdown button to be in same line with input box and icon in center of button ?

```
<form id="Form" class='form-fields'>
<div class='form-field'><label class='form-label' for='Klient0_nimi'><u style='cursor:default' >Klient</u></label><span id='span_Klient0_nimi'><input style='width:100px'  maxlenght='80'  id='Klient0_nimi' name='Klient0_nimi' ></input>
<button type='button' class='form-combobutton' tabindex=-1 ></button>
</span>
</div>

CSS:


.form-fields
{
    padding:10px; 
}

.form-field
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:2px; 
}


.form-label  
{
    padding-left:5px; 
    padding-right:5px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:xx-small;
}

.form-combobutton
{
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin-left:-6px ;
}


javascript:

    $("button", newel)
    .button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'} });
```

**Update**

both answers solve the alignment issue. However button width is very big, width: setting in style is ignored:

[image: wrong width]

How to set proper width?

```
<form id="Form" class='form-fields'>
<div class='form-field'><label class='form-label' for='Klient0_nimi'><u style='cursor:default' >Klient</u></label><span id='span_Klient0_nimi'>
<input  style='width:100px'  maxlenght='80'  id='Klient0_nimi' name='Klient0_nimi' value='' ></input>
<button class='form-combobutton' tabindex='-1'></button>
<script>$(function() {input_autocomplete($('#span_Klient0_nimi'), 'Klient0_nimi', 'DokG', 'KlientArvel') })</script>
</span>
</div>


javascript:

function input_autocomplete(newel, colName, entity, andmetp) {
    var input = $("input", newel);
    $(newel).parent().css({ display: "inline-block" }).parent().css({ 'padding-bottom': 0 });
    input.autocomplete({
        source: 'GetLookupList'
    }
   )
   .autocomplete('widget').css('font-size', '12px');

  $("button", newel).button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s' }, text: false });
}


css:


.form-fields
{
    padding:10px; 
}

.form-field
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:2px; 
}


.form-label  
{
    padding-left:5px; 
    padding-right:5px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:xx-small;
}

.form-combobutton
{   height: 22px;   
    margin: 0 0 2px;   
    padding: 0;   
    margin-left:-6px ;   
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 20px;   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) (`.button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'} });`) which add `.ui-button` CSS class having `position: relative`. So you should use `top` CSS property to set position of the botton:

```
.form-combobutton {
    /* other settings which you need */
    top:7px /* some value which looks good */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-combobutton
{
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   margin: 0 0 2px;
   padding: 0;
   margin-left:-6px ;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This should fix the issue